# Why we are using "printf '%s\n'" statement in replace of "echo" i m just new for shell script so help me to understand

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

```
secondLarge=`printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | sort -n | tail -2 | head -1`
```

I'm trying to get the second largest numbers and I got that, but if I'm trying with `echo` I can't get that. Help me to understand

```
secondLarge=`echo "${array[@]}" | sort -n | tail -2 | head -1`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) how is `"${array[@]}"` created and populated, ii) what are the contents of `"${array[@]}" `, iii) what is the output of the two commands, what do you get when you use `printf` and what do you get when you use `echo`?

Answer (score 4):

The GNU version of `printf` (typically installed at `/usr/bin/printf`) and the Bash built-in command of the same name both act like a loop when you pass more arguments to them than there are `%`-expandos in the format string.

Given:

```
declare -a array=( a b c )
```

Then:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Is more or less equivalent to:

```
for x in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo $x
done
```

Both of the above produce the following:

```
a
b
c
```

In contrast:

```
echo "${array[@]}"
```

Produces this:

```
a b c
```

Your pipeline sorts the output and then grabs the second-to-last line. With the `printf` example, every element in the array is printed on its own line, so you end up getting the second-to-largest numeric value in the array. If you're using `echo`, you only ever have one line to process, so you get a single line containing all of the array values.

Comment: "The GNU ... and the Bash builtin ... act like a loop when you pass more arguments to them than there are %" All `printf(1)` implementations act that way, not just the GNU and bash.